# Не срабатывает хендлер pre_checkout_query() Как исправить?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, aiogram-3.x

После ввода данных карточки и клика на "заплатить" платежный шлюз закрывается, а модульное окно инвойса от телеграма нет. И дальше - тишина.

Хендлеры @router.pre_checkout_query() и @router.message(F.successful_payment) не срабатывают

Что исправить в коде чтоб заработало?

```
"""Этот хендлер выставляет счета и показывает окно ввода карты"""
@router.callback_query((F.data == 'button_12_1_pressed')|
                       (F.data == 'button_13_pressed')|
                       (F.data == 'button_11_pressed'))
async def process_payment(callback: CallbackQuery, bot):
    pass
    elif callback.data == 'button_11_pressed':
        await bot.delete_message(callback.from_user.id, callback.message.message_id)
        await bot.send_invoice(chat_id=user_id_tg, title='Оформление подписки за 999',
                               description='Описание подписки за 999', payload='month sub 999',
                               provider_token='381764678:TEST:74022', currency='RUB',
                               start_parameter='test_999',
                               prices=[{'label':'руб.', 'amount':99900}])

        print(f'из button_11_pressed {callback.model_dump_json(indent=4, exclude_none=True)}')

# подтвердить наличие товара
@router.pre_checkout_query()
async def pre_checkout_query_handler(pre_checkout_query: PreCheckoutQuery, bot):
    print('подтверждаем')
    await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query.id, ok=True)
    print('подтвердили')

# успешный платеж
@router.message(F.successful_payment)
async def success_pay(message: Message):
    user_id_tg = message.from_user.id

    if message.successful_payment.invoice_payload == 'month sub 999':
        user_id_tg = message.from_user.id
        await message.answer(user_id_tg, text='Вы подписались за 999')
```

Comment: А вот этот вопрос и ответ читали: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1512223/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-telegram-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-aiogram-paymaent-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-pre-checkout-query-success

Comment: Читал. Ничего не перехватывается. Проверял. Срабатывает ровно 2 хендлера за все время: по команде /subscribe и по клику на 'button_11_pressed'

Comment: Блин все работает. Оказывается это я тупанул. Там после того как ввел данные и нажал на желтую кнопку "оплатить" потом надо еще раз в модульном окне телеги нажать "оплатить". А я третий раз не нажимал.